# Spring property binding with multiple separation

Tags: spring, properties

I have an application.property like this:

```
somevalue.api.test=something
somevalue.anotherproperty=stuff
```

I have made a configuration bean like this:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("somevalue")
public class SomeProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String apiTest;
    @NotNull
    private String anotherproperty;
}
```

Is it possible to refer to `api.test` like `apiTest`?

Mainly my issue is that I want to use the `somevalue` starting point for both property. I know if I don't separate with a dot the apiTest and I use it in this way `somevalue.api-test` I can refer to that with `apiTest` in my bean, but in my case it's not possible the renaming. So with dot separation can I achieve the same result or I should create two separate config bean, one refering to `somevalue.api` and the another only to `somevalue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't rename the property then no, you can't reference it using `String apiTest`. You need an additional class as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("somevalue")
public class GcssProperties {
    @NotNull
    private GcssApiProperties api;
    
    @NotNull
    private String anotherproperty;
}
```

```java
public class GcssApiProperties {
    @NotNull
    private String test;
}
```

This should work.